# How to use the parser "cron-expression"

Tags: php, vue.js, cron

I am trying to use the cron-job parser from this page:
https://packagist.org/packages/dragonmantank/cron-expression

The thing what isn't explained there, or I am overseeing it, is, how to give the parser a Cron-Expression so that the parser can work it out. I am a bit blind here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Scroll down to Usage. `$cron = Cron\CronExpression::factory('3-59/15 6-12 */15 1 2-5');`

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:vue.js]?

Comment: It's tagged vue.js because I use it in the project. But it's not important for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the static `factory` method of the `CronExpression` class.

```
<?php

$cron = Cron\CronExpression::factory('your-expression');

// do stuff with $cron
```

Comment: Do you mind accepting my answer for others to see? :-)

Comment: :) I dont mind, I already marked it green as a solution. What else do i have to do?

Comment: Nothing :) Thank you.